# How long are Heroku OAuth tokens valid when created with authorizations:create?

Tags: heroku, oauth

I'm using this to create a token:

```
heroku authorizations:create -d "Platform API example token"
```

How long will that stay valid?

If it doesn't stay valid forever, how can I create such a token (if possible)?

Answer (score 2):

from:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli-oauth

You can create a special user-created authorization against your account that will come with an access token which doesn't expire:

```
heroku authorizations:create --description "For use with Anvil"
```

Comment: Exactly. I read that and still wasn't sure. So what's the answer?